# How to filter rows where there are changes in a categorical variable

Tags: r, filter, subset

We have a dataframe called `data` with 2 columns: `Time` which is arranged in ascending order, and `Place` which describes where the individual was:

```
data.frame(Time = seq(1,20,1),
           Place = rep(letters[c(1:3,1)], c(5,5,3,7)))
```

Since this data is in ascending order with respect to `Time`, we want to subset the rows where `Place` changes from the previous observation.

The resulting dataframe for this data would look like this:

```
Time  Place
1      a
6      b
11     c
14     a
```

Notice that the same `Place` can show up later, like `Place == a` did in this example. How can we perform this kind of subset in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `duplicated` on the `rleid` of the 'Place'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   filter(!duplicated(rleid(Place)))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `rle`

```
subset(df1, !duplicated(with(rle(Place), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))))
```

-output

```
    Time Place
1     1     a
6     6     b
11   11     c
14   14     a
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `subset` + `tail` + `head`

```
subset(
    df,
    c(TRUE, tail(Place, -1) != head(Place, -1))
)
```

which gives

```
   Time Place
1     1     a
6     6     b
11   11     c
14   14     a
```

Comment: A similar option is `subset(df, c(TRUE, diff(match(Place, unique(Place))) != 0))`